# Hibernate Validator custom constraint not working

Tags: hibernate, constraints, hibernate-validator

I am trying to create a custom contraint with Hibernate Validator.
If I use a standard one such as @Size, it's work well and I got the error message.
However, my custom one is not working and I cannot figure why.

This is my code:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = TestValidateur.class)



public @interface ObjectValid {


    String message() default "test";
     
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    
}
```

And:

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;



public  class TestValidateur implements ConstraintValidator<ObjectValid , String>  {

      public void initialize(ObjectValid constraintAnnotation) {
        
      }

    public boolean isValid(String NoObject, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {

         return false ;
    
}

}
```

```
@Column(name="NoObject")
@ObjectValid
@Size(min = 4, max = 14)
public String NoObject;
```

And to test the validation:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.hibernate.mapping.Component;
import org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator;


import jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import jakarta.validation.Validation;
import jakarta.validation.Validator;
import jakarta.validation.ValidatorFactory;



public class NoTest {
    private static Validator validator;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {


       Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
       Object objectVerif = new Object("ss");
       Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> validationErrors = validator.validate(objectVerif);
       if(!validationErrors.isEmpty()){
           for(ConstraintViolation<Object> error : validationErrors){
               System.out.println(error);

       }

       }  

}
}
```

If I run the app, I only receive the error message for the @Size

```
ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='la taille doit être comprise entre 4 et 14', propertyPath=NoObject, rootBeanClass=class tp03.Object, messageTemplate='{jakarta.validation.constraints.Size.message}'}
```

If anyone has a clue of what I a am missing, it would be really appreciated

thank you

Validated object:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.Min;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Null;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name="object",indexes = { @Index(name="primary",columnList = "idObject")})

public class Object {

    
    
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="idObject")    
private int idObject;

public int getidObject()
{
    {return idObject;}
}

public void SetidObject(int idObject)
{
    
    this.idObject=idObject;
}


@Column(name="NoObject")
@ObjectValid
@Size(min = 4, max = 14)
public String NoObject;


public String getNoObject()
{
    {return NoObject;}
}

public void SetNoObject(String NoObject)
{
    
    this.NoObject=NoObject;
}

public Object(String NoObject)
{this.NoObject=NoObject;
}


}
```

Comment: Hi, just for completeness, can you share more of your validated Object, so that one can try to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the `javax.validation.Constraint` was used for defining the custom constraint, but the `jakarta.validation.Validator` is used for carrying out the validation, which then only validates `jakarta.validation.Constraint`s.

If you change your imports from `javax` to `jakarta` in the `ObjectValid` constraint interface and the `TestValidateur` class, both constraints are validated correctly.